# inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'email.queue' in vhost 'Email': received none but current is the value 'quorum' of type 'longstr'

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have WSO2 project which has RabbitMQ message store configured as follows:

```
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore" name="EmailErrorPendingMS" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.name">rabbitmq-staging</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.port">5672</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.route.key">email.key</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.username">guest</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.virtual.host">Email</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.exchange.name">email.exchange</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.queue.name">email.queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.password">guest</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

When running the project I am getting the following exception:

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MessageStoreFactory} - Successfully added Message Store configuration of : [EmailMS].
INFO {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore} - Store [EmailMS] Successfully connected to RabbitMQ Broker
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore} - Store [EmailMS]. Initialization failed... java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:968)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclare(AutorecoveringChannel.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore.declareQueue(RabbitMQStore.java:308)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore.init(RabbitMQStore.java:125)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageStoreDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(MessageStoreDeployer.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:205)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1129)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:139)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:189)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:227)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
    Suppressed: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'email.queue' in vhost 'Email': received none but current is the value 'quorum' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.processShutdownSignal(AMQChannel.java:401)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.startProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:292)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:613)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:547)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:540)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.close(AutorecoveringChannel.java:73)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore.init(RabbitMQStore.java:128)
        ... 74 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'email.queue' in vhost 'Email': received none but current is the value 'quorum' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'email.queue' in vhost 'Email': received none but current is the value 'quorum' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:522)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:719)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:646)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the RabbitMQ admin console? If it is the case, can you check what is currently configured?

Comment: @Olivier, yes I have but what exactly I should check for?

Comment: If the configuration you requested is already present (exchange **mail.exchange**, queue **mail.queue**, and specifically what are the attributes of the queue if already present (is it a classic or quorum queue)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code of the RabbitMQ Message Store https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/728985f1b68dd241e336f66ac312847c12417f10/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/rabbitmq/RabbitMQStore.java#L307

```java
    private void declareQueue(Channel channel, String queueName) throws IOException {
            channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, new HashMap<String, Object>());
        }
```

As you can see, the queue properties is an empty HashMap, and in the case of a `quorum` queue `x-queue-type: quorum`

For detail, see [Declaration and Property Equivalence](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#property-equivalence)

Therefore, when redeclaring an existing queue or exchange with non-matching properties will fail with a 406 PRECONDITION_FAILED error

If you decide to go with quorum queue, you have to extend the Message Store class to support parameter in `declareQueue` function